# How to combine data from different tables using a query

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2012

I have a set of tables that look like what I have shown below.

Could you let me know how I can achive the desired output ?

```
CREATE TABLE #ABC([Year] INT, [Month] INT,Customer Varchar(10), SalesofProductA INT);
CREATE TABLE #DEF([Year] INT, [Month] INT,Customer Varchar(10), SalesofProductB INT);
CREATE TABLE #GHI([Year] INT, [Month] INT,Customer Varchar(10), SalesofProductC INT);

INSERT #ABC VALUES (2013,1,'PPP',1);
INSERT #ABC VALUES (2013,1,'QQQ',2);
INSERT #ABC VALUES (2013,2,'PPP',3);

INSERT #DEF VALUES (2013,1,'QQQ',4);
INSERT #DEF VALUES (2013,1,'RRR',5);
INSERT #DEF VALUES (2013,2,'PPP',6);

INSERT #GHI VALUES (2013,1,'QQQ',7);
INSERT #GHI VALUES (2013,2,'RRR',8);
INSERT #GHI VALUES (2013,3,'PPP',9);
   INSERT #GHI VALUES (2013,3,'QQQ',10);
```

I have a query currently that looks like this . @Month and @Year are supplied as parameters

```
SELECT
    -- select the sum for each year/month combination using a correlated subquery (each result from the main query causes another data retrieval operation to be run)
    (SELECT SUM(SalesofProductA) FROM #ABC WHERE [Year]=T.[Year] AND [Month]=T.[Month]) AS [Sum_SalesofProductA]
    ,(SELECT SUM(SalesofProductB) FROM #DEF WHERE [Year]=T.[Year] AND [Month]=T.[Month]) AS [Sum_SalesofProductB]
    ,(SELECT SUM(SalesofProductC) FROM #GHI WHERE [Year]=T.[Year] AND [Month]=T.[Month]) AS [Sum_SalesofProductC]
FROM (
    -- this selects a list of all possible dates.
    SELECT [Year],[Month] FROM #ABC
    where Year = @Year and Month = @Month
    UNION
    SELECT [Year],[Month] FROM #DEF
    where Year = @Year and Month = @Month
     UNION
    SELECT [Year],[Month] FROM #GHI
    where Year = @Year and Month = @Month
) AS T;
```

Right now I see an output like this : for a particular value of @Month and @Year

```
 SalesofProductA, SalesofProductB, SalesofProductC
```

What I would like to see is :

```
[Customer],SalesofProductA, SalesofProductB, SalesofProductC
```

Does anyone know how it can be done ?

Comment: Why have you tagged this question with three versions of SQL Server? Are you looking for a solution for every one of the three?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Customer 
          , SUM(COALESCE(P.[ProductA], 0)) AS [ProductA] 
          , SUM(COALESCE(P.[ProductB], 0)) AS [ProductB] 
          , SUM(COALESCE(P.[ProductC], 0)) AS [ProductC] 
FROM
(
SELECT Customer , SUM(SalesofProductA) AS  Sales, 'ProductA' AS ProductName 
FROM #ABC 
GROUP BY Customer
UNION ALL 
SELECT Customer , SUM(SalesofProductB) AS  Sales, 'ProductB' AS ProductName 
FROM #DEF 
GROUP BY Customer
UNION ALL 
SELECT Customer , SUM(SalesofProductC) AS  Sales, 'ProductC' AS ProductName 
FROM #GHI 
GROUP BY Customer
) Q
   PIVOT ( SUM(Sales) 
           FOR ProductName
           IN ([ProductA], [ProductB], [ProductC])
           )P
GROUP BY  Customer
```

**Result**

```
Customer    ProductA    ProductB    ProductC
PPP             4          6           9
QQQ             2          4           17
RRR             0          5           8
```

Comment: I am soo sorry. I just edited my question again.. I had it wrong the first time. I am looking for the Customer , ProductA,ProductB and ProductC for a particular month and year ..

Comment: I believe you need to throw in a filter on `@Year` and `@Month` somewhere. Also, it is unnecessary to explicitly group on `Customer` in the outer query as the grouping has already been done by PIVOT.